# Raspberry PI mdns getaddrinfo 3008 error

Tags: node.js, raspberry-pi, raspbian, mdns, raspberry-pi2

I've this sample Node.js script:

```
var mdns = require('mdns');

var browser = mdns.createBrowser(mdns.tcp('http'));
browser.on('error', function (error) {
    console.log("error");
    console.log(error);
});
browser.on('serviceUp', function (service) {
    console.log("serviceUp");
    console.log(service);
});
browser.start();
```

On my Mac it's working fine, and two services is found. If I run the exact same script on my *Raspberry PI 2* running *Raspbean* (connected to the same network), I get this output:

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ node mdns.js 
*** WARNING *** The program 'node' uses the Apple Bonjour compatibility layer of Avahi.
*** WARNING *** Please fix your application to use the native API of Avahi!
*** WARNING *** For more information see <http://0pointer.de/avahi-compat?s=libdns_sd&e=node>
*** WARNING *** The program 'node' called 'DNSServiceRegister()' which is not supported (or only supported partially) in the Apple Bonjour compatibility layer of Avahi.
*** WARNING *** Please fix your application to use the native API of Avahi!
*** WARNING *** For more information see <http://0pointer.de/avahi-compat?s=libdns_sd&e=node&f=DNSServiceRegister>
error
{ [Error: getaddrinfo -3008] code: -3008, errno: -3008, syscall: 'getaddrinfo' }
error
{ [Error: getaddrinfo -3008] code: -3008, errno: -3008, syscall: 'getaddrinfo' }
```

A [issue on the mdns GitHub](https://github.com/agnat/node_mdns/issues/129), states that it's fair to ignore the warnings.

But what about the two errors? Is that some kind of configuration issue on my *Raspberry PI*?

Comment: Just for your information, `getaddrinfo` error codes can be translated into human-readable text using `gai_strerror`, defined in [`netdb.h`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xns/netdb.h.html). Unfortunately, the error code -3008 is represented as "Unknown error". My guess is that the error code comes from somewhere else than the `getaddrinfo` function, perhaps some underlying system call or whatever...

Comment: which version of node.js is running on the raspberry pi?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solution was found on this GitHub issue:
https://github.com/agnat/node_mdns/issues/130

Modify *Browser.defaultResolverSequence* inside *lib/browser.js* in mdns.

```
Browser.defaultResolverSequence = [
  rst.DNSServiceResolve(), 'DNSServiceGetAddrInfo' in dns_sd ? rst.DNSServiceGetAddrInfo() : rst.getaddrinfo({families:[4]})
, rst.makeAddressesUnique()
];
```

Answer (score 5):

It's a bad practice to modify node modules code locally.

You should better do the following when you create a mdns Browser:

```
var sequence = [
  mdns.rst.DNSServiceResolve(),
  'DNSServiceGetAddrInfo' in mdns.dns_sd ? mdns.rst.DNSServiceGetAddrInfo() : mdns.rst.getaddrinfo({families:[4]}),
  mdns.rst.makeAddressesUnique()
];
var browser = mdns.createBrowser(mdns.tcp('http'), {resolverSequence: sequence});
```

Like said in this comment: https://github.com/agnat/node_mdns/issues/130#issuecomment-120731155

Thus, it will avoid bugs and allow everybody working on the project to get the same version and don't have to modify locally mdns code.